# Does entity-framework apply filters/orders on csharp side or the Database's side?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

For example In my controller I have something like

```
var johnDoe = Teachers.Where(t=>t.Name == "John Doe");
```

Does it retrieve all the teacher in the Database and then filter it from C# side

Or does it retrieve only the "John Doe" Teacher/s from my database?

Comment: I certainly hope on the DB side. Otherwise, this would a most crappy and ultra slow environment.

Comment: Just curious, why would you expect it to be executed on the client?

Answer (score 4):

Your linq statement will be translated into SQL code, then send to the server. The filtering happens on the server side and the result will be returned **filtered** to you.

This [article](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-and-linq-to-entities-5-query-translation) explains in detail how the translation goes along.

This [documentation on LINQ to Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities) has a large set of topic around the execution of queries

Comment: So to sum it up. The Linq that we do from Lists<T> is different from the Linq of a DbSet<T>. Is it correct?

Comment: @anaval in short : yes

Comment: @anaval to be more precise - LINQ you do on `IEnumerable<T>` is somewhat different than you do on `IQueryable<T>`.